# AppCompact V7 being added

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been developing my android app for a couple of months (this has not been a good experience) in Eclipse with the ADT add-on. Before I just had my project and when I added an an Activity it created the .Java file and the XML file.

Now when I add an Activity it tries to add an appcompact_v7 project to my workspace. This is breaking everything and I will no longer compile. Why is it doing this and why is eclipse so awful?

Ok further investigation it seems that the Blank Activity template is now creating an Activity based on ActionBarActivity rather than Activity! When did this change? Why did this change!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is bad form to answer with a link, but commonsware did address this a few days ago. http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/15/really-blank-activity-why-appcompat-shoved-down-your-throat.html

basically

"The issue is that the activity templates in Eclipse’s ADT — or at least BlankActivity, as I have not bothered with the others very recently — are set up to have you use ActionBarActivity and appcompat_v7. Technically, creating a project via the new-project wizard does not add appcompat_v7, but creating an activity via the new-activity wizard does. This includes checking the “create activity” checkbox in the new-project wizard, which effectively chains to the new-activity wizard."

As to why eclipse is so awful, that is a much longer discussion and has been talked about in an endless number of forums.

Comment: I was slightly off in my analysis. The copying of `appcompat_v7` and attaching it to the project is either the fault of the `NewAndroidApplication` template or is possibly baked into the new-project wizard. Having activities inherit from `ActionBarActivity` and related stuff is from the `BlankActivity` template. My `ReallyBlankActivity` template solves the latter. I am still working on getting `appcompat_v7` to not be added in the first place. Also, reputedly, some of this will be addressed in the next ADT update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated android SDK Tools or Android SDK Platform tools recently? 
I solved that problem reinstalling ADT and not upgrading it

edit: you can delete the appcompact_v7 from your proyect, go to proyect properties->android and delete the appcompact_v7 library
[image: http://i.imgur.com/7cs7NYP.png]